How to add templates to your images using the Webmorph package in R
I've uploaded images to R that I want to process with the Webmorph package, especially manipulate the face colour. However, I cannot workout how to 'add a template to these images' as I kept getting the error code "Error: No images had templates"
I have only found functions that require a template

Welcome to SO!
Please include a minimal reproducible example, as shown in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/11809780
